# Фильтры на сайте никак не влияют на ссылку сайта (парсинг)

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть сайт с которого нужно спарсить список состоящий из названий фильмов. Проблема заключается в том, что фильмы и сериалы находятся на одной страничке, а при фильтрации на самом сайте ссылка не меняется и я никак не могу дать парсеру понять что мне нужны только фильмы. Использование фильтров на сайте вообще никак не влияет на ссылку, что делать в такой ситуации?

Сайт с которого я пытаюсь парсить: [https://hd.filmshd.top/xfsearch/genre/мелодрама/](https://hd.filmshd.top/xfsearch/genre/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/)

```
def sandbox (base_url, headers):
movies = []
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
if request.status_code == 200:
    soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
    divs = soup.select('div.th-item')
    for div in divs:
        name = div.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'th-tip-title'}).text
        movies.append(name)
    print(movies)
else:
    print('FAILED')
```

Comment: Я обычно начинаю парсинг с поиска карты сайта. Её наличие многие подобные вопросы снимает.
[Карта сайта](https://hd.filmshd.top/sitemap.xml)

Comment: @Voko карта сайта - это, конечно, хорошо, но решить вопрос вообще никак не помогает в данном случае.

Comment: @Voko как карта сайта поможет спарсить данные которые подгружаются через ajax? (как в данном случае)

Comment: @Voko солидарен с комментарием выше, карта сайта никак не помогает в решении данной проблемы...

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать категорию в параметрах запроса
**(Но при этом нужно использовать метод POST)**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def sandbox(base_url):
    movies = []
    payloads = {"xsort": "1", "xs_field": "category", "xs_value": "1"}
    # "xs_value": "1" - Это фильмы
    # "xs_value": "2" - Это сериалы

    session = requests.Session()

    request = session.post(base_url, data=payloads)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'th-item'})

        for div in divs:
            name = div.find('div', {'class': 'th-tip-title'}).text
            movies.append(name)
        print(movies)
    else:
        print('FAILED')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sandbox('https://hd.filmshd.top/xfsearch/genre/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/')
```

Или отфильтровать ее в процессе обработки `Soup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def sandbox(base_url):
    movies = []

    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'th-item'})
        for div in divs:            
            if 'сезон' not in div.select_one('div', {'class': 'th-meta th-qual'}).text.strip():
                name = div.find('div', {'class': 'th-tip-title'}).text
                movies.append(name)
        print(movies)
    else:
        print('FAILED')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sandbox('https://hd.filmshd.top/xfsearch/genre/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/')
# ['Хорошие новозди', 'Маленькие женщины', 'Уловки страсти: Девушка встречает парня', 'Повторим?', 'История любви из параллельного мира', 'Всем парням: P.S. Я люблю тебя', 'Принцесса Монако', 'Босиком по городу', 'Малефисента', 'Легионы']
```

Ну или вот так можно собрать названия со всех страниц с фильмами:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests


def sandbox(base_url):
    movies = []
    payloads = {"xsort": "1", "xs_field": "category", "xs_value": "1"}

    with requests.Session() as session:

        request = session.post(base_url, data=payloads)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            soup = Soup(request.content, 'html.parser')
            pages_qty = int(soup.find('div', {'class': 'navigation'}).find_all('a')[-1].text)

            for page in range(1, pages_qty + 1):
                page_url = base_url + f'page/{page}/'

                html = session.get(page_url)
                if request.status_code == 200:
                    soup = Soup(html.content, 'html.parser')
                    divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'th-item'})

                    for div in divs:
                        name = div.find('div', {'class': 'th-tip-title'}).text
                        movies.append(name)

                else:
                    print('FAILED')

            print(movies)
        else:
            print('FAILED')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sandbox('https://hd.filmshd.top/xfsearch/genre/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/')
```